# newfeed items disappear

Tags: 2013, newsfeed, distributedcache

We have a 2013 farm with the social stuff enabled.
People are complaining that whatever they post on newsfeed is being lost.

I suppose that this is related to the distributed cache service, I read somewhere that the time to live is 14 days.

So the questions are?,

1. Can I change the newsfeed to show items over more time?
2. When I install or update solutions, this involves IISRESET of all servers, and restart of all timer jobs, does this clean the distributed cache service?
3. If 2nd is true, how can I avoid that the newsfeed items are not lost?

Is it possible to have cache servers that are not neccesarily restarted when we install wsps?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis,

This question is similar to yours:
[SharePoint 2013 My Site Newsfeed Posts Disappear](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6a415c75-4ca3-4c43-9110-25a68db93a54/sharepoint-2013-my-site-newsfeed-posts-disappear?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Following are quotes from answers:

> A second concern when cached data in SharePoint is lost is that some
>   items in SharePoint are *only* stored in the cache; specifically,
>   updates regarding followed documents are only stored in the cache (as
>   of March 2013). If these cached items are lost they won’t be able to
>   be regenerated and will no longer appear in users’ feeds.
>
> To avoid losing items from the cache and/or having to retrieve them
>   again, you can use the Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance cmdlet
>   with the -Graceful switch. This will move all cached items from the
>   local cache host to other cache hosts in the cluster.
>
> from
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-2.aspx
>
> ---
>
> So if a reboot or iisreset is performed and the distributed cache is
>   flushed then all followed newsfeeds are removed? To prevent this from
>   being lost we would neet to stop SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
>   with the -Graceful Switch and then perform the reset? It looks like in
>   the article you referenced that the TimeToLive for Activity feed is
>   set at 168 hours or 7 days. I suppose that the Activity Feed is only
>   stored in cache and therefore has an expiration so as to not fill up
>   memory.
>
> ---
>
> They are removed after 14 days. This is built into the feeds and
>   normal. However they are moved to a second list not deleted in 2013
>   and they should load when you click to "View more activity".
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219766.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can get an understanding into the Micro-blogging feature in SP 2013 and distributed cache over here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219700.aspx