# Newsfeed Posts Disappear

Tags: my-site, newsfeed, app-fabric

My post in the newsfeed disappear after 1 min and trying to change the cache for the appfabric but it's not working and i stuck here how i can change this setting for my newsfeed  ?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88884/newfeed-items-disappear

Comment: i try this Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance -graceful  and then i restart the iis  but still my post in newsfeed disappear

Comment: How many servers in the farm? are the cache running on all servers?

Comment: only one server for sharepoint 2013 and sql install on the same server

Comment: Have the newsfeed worked before? did you apply any patches recently?

Comment: yes it's worked before but it's seems after posting more than 10 or 15 post this problem start appearing .

Comment: @Abdullah are you able to solve it ?